# Trigonometric substitution, bounds and which root to pick.

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have been using trigonometric substitution for a while now, I can do it almost automatically. I understand it is a kind of "reverse" u-substitution. However, what concerns me are the bounds. How do we calculate the bounds? What is the rigor behind it? Also, when we do trig stuff, we usually pick $\sqrt{\tan^2{\theta}}=\tan{\theta}$. How do we pick which root we should choose? I assume it is dependent on the bounds?

Comment: $\sqrt{\tan^2{\theta}}=|\tan{\theta}|$ If you enter appropriate intervals where the tangent is positive then you can remove the absolute value.

Comment: This is a rather broad question.  And I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but with respect to the bounds of integration in a definite integral in which you're using trig substitution, at the time of substitution, e.g. letting $x = \tan \theta$ (and $x^2 = \tan^2 \theta$), and the original integral is of the form $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, then, in addition to determining $dx = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$, you'll also want to evaluate what $\tan \theta$ is, when $x=a$, (solving $\tan \theta = a$) and what $\tan \theta$ is, when $x=b$.

Comment: @amWhy so no matter what $a,b$ are, I can find the $\theta$ since $tan$ is surjective. Since $\tan$ is periodic I understand I have to be careful to pick such $\theta$ that they are in the same period.

Comment: For example, if $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, we need to find a theta such that $\tan \theta = 0$.  The natural choice would be to let $\theta = 0$, and we need to find theta such that $\tan \theta = 1$ the natural choice would be $\theta = \frac \pi 4$.

Comment: Now if $a = -1$, and $b=1$, the values needed for $\theta$ would different (at least in the case of $a$.